# Creating a Datetimepicker in screen painter in SAP Business One

Tags: visual-studio, sapb1

I'm new to using screen painter and I am trying to make a payroll add -on for SAP B1. The payroll application I have right now, I made in C# .NET. The forms are winforms and I want to make them again with screen painter using SAP B1 8.81 PL 4.

On the toolbox for screen painter, I do not see any datetimepicker that I can drag onto the form unlike in Visual Studio.

So how do I get to have a datetimepicker using screenpainter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- add a "Text Field"
- then go to its attributes (by double clicking) and change the data format to "Date"

Comment: I do not see an option for data format. I have added an Editbox as they call it on the form. There are 5 tabs in the properties window and I am at the items tab and no place to change the data format

Comment: oh, sorry I was referring to the SAP screenpainter. there we have "Attributes" and under "Dict" there is a "Format" field. is there nothing similar in the b1 screen painter? I guess you map the editbox to a variable. try mapping it to a variable with the type for a date (in sap its DATS)

Answer (score 0):

to make a text field as Date picker type we need to bind that field with a date field in a sap b1 table or using userdata sources through coding. 
after adding this we need to enable option for date in view-> pickers display in menu.